# How to create an instace in AWS ec2 through .net SDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-net

I am trying to create an instance in AWS EC2 but the line

```
RunInstancesResponse launchResponse = ec2Client.RunInstances(launchRequest);
```

causes an exception:

> AmazonEC2Client.RunInstances(RunInstanceRequest) is inaccessible due to it's protection level

Below is my code.  I've tried using `RunInstanceAsync` instead but it also didn't work.

```cs
var launchRequest = new RunInstancesRequest()
{
    ImageId = amiID,
    InstanceType = "t2.micro",
    MinCount = 1,
    MaxCount = 1,
    KeyName = keyPairName,
    NetworkInterfaces = enis
};
        
RunInstancesResponse launchResponse = ec2Client.RunInstances(launchRequest);
       
List<String> instanceIds = new List<string>();
        
foreach (Instance instance in launchResponse.Reservation.Instances)
{
    Console.WriteLine(instance.InstanceId);
    instanceIds.Add(instance.InstanceId);
}
```

Comment: what version of the SDK are you using?  And is your project Core or Framework?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using the .NET Core version of the SDK. In .NET Core only the async operations are supported. So you need to call `RunInstancesAsync`.

Comment: Doesn't the question say that was already tried and did not work?